# get the text from jTextField using jTextField1KeyTyped event

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I have a `jTextField`, and when I want to type something in it, I want it to be displayed.

I used the `jTextField1KeyTyped` event.

but the problem is when I press some text the console shows me the text from the `jTextField` minus the last char.

for example if I typed "abcde", it will show me only "abcd".

how can I resolve this issue.

## EDIT :

this is my project :

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package Personel;

/**
 *
 * @author aimad
 */
public class SelectionArticle extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form SelectionProduit
     */
    public SelectionArticle() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        jLabel1.setText("jLabel1");

        jTextField1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextField1KeyTyped(evt);
            }
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                jTextField1KeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 264, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
        System.out.println("Key typed : " + jTextField1.getText());
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectionArticle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectionArticle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectionArticle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SelectionArticle.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new SelectionArticle().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame with only one JComponent == JTextField, otherwise you would need look at DocumentListener

Comment: @mKorbel okey, please see the modification I made

Comment: Such auto-generated layouts should be forbidden in an SSCCE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- add [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) instead of [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to [JTextComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html)
- then you can to listening for [string inserted, removed or replaced whole String in `JTextComponent`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10848530/714968), otherwise all mentioned events aren't possible to catch by `KeyListener`

Comment: get code from my example and then to replace jTextField1.addKeyListener....., don't know how to set that in any of GUI Buileder, there must be properties for that

Comment: okey, I have set the DocumentListener event to my JTextFIield, but now how can I get the text which is typed in the jTextField ?

Comment: there are three methods, debug and see whats happened after char typed into JTextfield